# Infinite scroll execute action twice or more

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll. Everything is working great except one thing.

When the user scroll to the end, I perform an asynchronous request using $.getScript that add content to the page. But sometimes (too often), this action is performed twice.

How can I perform this action only once until it reach the end of the page again?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var more_posts_url;

  // Get the URL of the next page
  more_posts_url = $('.next_page').attr('href');

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200) {
    console.log("LOADING PAGE "+more_posts_url);
    // Call the next page and render it (via my back-end)
    $.getScript(more_posts_url);
  }
});
```

In my console I get:

```
LOADING PAGE /pages/?page=2
LOADING PAGE /pages/?page=2
LOADING PAGE /pages/?page=3
LOADING PAGE /pages/?page=3
LOADING PAGE /pages/?page=3
LOADING PAGE /pages/?page=4
LOADING PAGE /pages/?page=5
...
```

This happens even if I do not scroll like a crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I was sending a request both in Ajax, and via a remote form...